# Sequence of time(hour)

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, sequence

I tried:

```
seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23", tz="UTC"),
     by="hour"
   )
```

But I only get 1 hour(0:00:00) of the last day instead of 24 hours, actually any hour of the day resulted in only one hour(0:00:00), and I do want to have 2012-1-4.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Specify the time in full?

```
seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23:00", tz="UTC"),
     by="hour"
   )
```

Answer (score 5):

You did not use a standard format for the dates.  See `?as.POSIXct`.

Try this

```
seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
    to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-03 23:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")
```

Answer (score 5):

You could specify a format:

```
seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
     by="hour"
   )
```

Comment: Is there a by="half hour" option?

Comment: "by = 30 min" ended up being more successful.